# Get the index of a character or a substring by reversely loop in Python

Tags: java, python, loops, substring

Here is what I want to do in Java, however I need to implement this into Python.

```
String foo = new String("Foo's bar");
for (int i = foo.length-1; i--; i>=0) {
    if(foo[i] == '\'') {
        String bar = foo.substring(0,i);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is find a key character from the last character to the very first one once I find it I need to substring the rest part (Imagine get someone's name from a phrase).

Answer (score 2):

Try `rfind()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind

```
foo = "Foo's bar'"
index_to = foo.rfind("'", 0, len(foo))
print foo[0:index_to]
>>> Foo
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is quite easy. You will get a list of splited elements. Pick the first one.

```
"Foo's bar".split("\'")[0]
```